# How to display my data from a text-file determined by a combo box?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, text-files, data-retrieval

I am trying to retrieve a surfer from a list on a textfile, the user selects the surfer from the combo box which then displays that surfers data in a bunch of labels. My code requires each surfer to have an ID for it to be able to know which record to retrieve from the database. However when I try to put my ID from my loop together with each surfers name, I receive an error saying "Conversion from string to type 'Long' is not valid." I have tried different methods of getting around this, none of which have worked. Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Lookup_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    madelabel = False
    For i = 1 To maxrecJudge
        FileGet(2, ajudge, i)
        recnoJudge = i
        judgename = recnoJudge And " " And ajudge.name
        cmbJudge.Items.Add(judgename)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To maxrecSurfer
        FileGet(1, asurfer, i)
        recnoSurfer = i
        surfername = recnoSurfer And " " And asurfer.name
        cmbSurfer.Items.Add(surfername)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub cmbSurfer_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbSurfer.SelectedIndexChanged
    recnoSurfer = CInt(Val(New Text.StringBuilder((From ch In cmbSurfer.Text.ToCharArray Where IsNumeric(ch)).ToArray).ToString))
    FileGet(1, asurfer, recnoSurfer)
    If madelabel = False Then
        lblName = New Label
        lblName.Top = 160
        lblName.Left = 253
        lblName.Autosize = True
        lblName.Text = asurfer.name
        Me.Controls.Add(lblName) 
End Sub
```

For simplicity I have only included one label creation above, but there are several labels spawned each with data of the surfer.

Am I on the right track with this? In the second sub my code extracts the integer (ID) from the combo box which then is used as a record number to find the rest of the data. The error relates to these lines:

```
            surfername = recnoSurfer And " " And asurfer.name
            cmbSurfer.Items.Add(surfername)
```

It won't let me concatenate the ID and the surfers name. Any help?

Comment: You need to use `&` for concatenation, not `And`.

Comment: `&` or even `+` would work here for concatenation, `And` and `AndAlso` are usually used for comparison. @Blackwood your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a lot of concatenation, use a StringBuilder. It is far quicker. Every time you concatenation strings, a new string is created. Over a large amount of iterations, StringBuilder is the better choice.